# Will I achieve triple-channelness with 9x4GB

Tags: memory, triple-channel

I'm planning to build a rig with [EVGA SR-2](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=270-WS-W555-A2) inside.
It supports triple channel and has 12 memory slots.

The question is whether I will achieve triple channelness if i install 9x4GB identical DDR3 memory?

Well I assume I will, but nothing's wrong in making sure :)

Comment: Read your motherboard's manual and find out.  I'm voting to close this question as too localized, especially given the general narrative of the current answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the manual and this is what I discovered.  I would say more but the manual answers your question.

[image: EVGA Classified Super Record 2 (SR-2) Dual Xeon Motherboard]

[270-WS-W555-A2 - Manual](http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/270-WS-W555.pdf)

Comment: I would like to point out its unlikely your motherboard supports a 6 + 3 configuration. I should also point out to use the other set of DDR3 DIMMs you will need two processors installed on the motherboard.  I can say that it doesn't support a 6+ 3 configuration based on the fact it doesn't say it does support it and based on the 2/4 3/6 required configuration.